# Как запретить вывод одной из категорий портфолио в общую категорию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Есть вёрстка портфолио. В нём есть несколько разделов.

Работы в портфолио распределяются по разделам.
Так же, присутствует раздел "Всё" - куда попадают работы из всех разделов.

Появился вопрос : как запретить вывод определённых работ из определённых разделов в общий раздел "Всё" ?

Например я хочу, чтобы эта работа из раздела "Первая категория" не попала в раздел "Всё". Как можно запретить вывод ? 
[image: Это скриншот]

Вот прикладываю ссылку на сайт ( это версия для теста ) :[Ссылка на сайт](http://welldan.esy.es/demo/)

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: чтобы "запретить вывод" нам бы узнать про "ввод" - как они попадают в раздел "Всё" ?

Comment: @qwabra, как-то так - https://jsfiddle.net/0vzojuyt/1/

Answer (score 0):

У вас на каждой кнопке категорий есть условия для фильтрации, в атрибуте data-filter, согласно которому отображаются те или иные картинки.

```
<div class="portfolio-menu portfolio-left-menu text-center mb-50">
                    <button class="active" data-filter="*">Всё</button>
                    <button data-filter=".mix1">Категория 1 </button>
                    <button data-filter=".mix2">Категория 2 </button>
                    <button data-filter=".mix3">Категория 3 </button>
                    <button data-filter=".mix4">Категория 4 </button>
</div>
```

Изображениям присвоены классы как и в data-filter: .mix1,.mix2 и т.д

При клике на раздел, вы получаете класс и отфильтровываете изображения с этим же классом для их отображения:

```
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
```

На кнопке "Всё" передается *, что означает отобразить все. Чтоб убрать какое либо изображение из меню "Всё", задайте там другое условие для фильтрации.

Comment: Не подскажите какое условие для фильтрации сделать ? )

Comment: Я не знаю какое именно условие Вам надо. Решение в лоб: добавить всем картинка класс .mix5. В условие поставить:<button class="active" data-filter=".mix5">Всё</button>
Картинке которая не должна отображаться, класс .mix5 не добавлять.

Comment: Блин, в который раз убеждаюсь, что всё гениальное просто. 
Уже всё перепробовал и искал какие-то сложные подходы через javascript. А решение было на поверхности. 
Спасибо большое! Это то, что нужно.